# firebase function https.onRequest with async fails eslint

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I have the firebase function as

```
exports.oauth = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
```

for which the eslint throws error as below

```
  11:69  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions currently runs node 6, which does not support async/await syntax in ECMAScript 2017.  If you want to use async/await, you should be using TypeScript or something else which transpiles down to equivalent code that runs on node 6.

Comment: `"engines": {"node": "8"}` is [now available](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions).